# Elixir: Update a specific value in a list of maps

Tags: elixir

Given the following list of maps:

```elixir
ball_prop_list = 
[
  %{"id" => "cue", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => -15.0, "z" => 0.0},
  %{"id" => "ball_1", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 15.0, "z" => 0.0},
  %{"id" => "ball_2", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 17.0, "z" => 1.1},
  %{"id" => "ball_3", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 17.0, "z" => -1.1}
]
```

How do I go about changing, say, just the `velocity_x` and `velocity_y` of `"id" => "cue"`, and keeping everything else the same?

I've only gotten as far as trying to create a new list (which was not necessarily my goal) with updated values, such as the following:

```elixir
new_prop_list = Enum.map(balls_json_list, fn(val) -> 
  if val["id"] == "cue" do
    Map.put(val, "velocity_x" velocity_vector[:x])
    Map.put(val, "velocity_z" velocity_vector[:z])
  end
end)
```

But this didn't work out, probably because my maps do not use atom keys - every other example I've seen so far uses atom keys, or adds a new key and value, etc.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: If it's something you are going to be doing frequently, you might want to consider converting your list to a map, so you can look up by id and avoid iterating the list every time.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I'll keep that in mind, thanks! For now I'm just following the format the rest of the program demands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Map.put/3` does not modify the map in-place (because no data structure in Elixir can be modified), but creates a new map.

Also, you missed 2 commas.

```elixir
new_ball_prop_list = Enum.map(ball_prop_list, fn
  %{"id" => "cue"} = map ->
    map
    |> Map.put("velocity_x", velocity[:x])
    |> Map.put("velocity_y", velocity[:y])
  other_map ->
    other_map
end)
```

You can also try `Map.merge/2` or `%{map | k1 => v1, k2 => v2}`

Comment: If I were to do an operation or some sort of calculation before updating those values, where would I put that in, with your code above?

Comment: @zack_falcon Under the first `->`, that is, inside the first clause of the anonymous function. By the way, technically it's perfectly valid to put as many expressions as you want inside any of the clauses.

Answer (score 8):

There is extremely underrated [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html) in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) that is way more powerful, especially when it comes to deep updates.

Even despite in this particular case the straightforward `Map.put/3` might seem easier, I’d post the solution with [`update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#update_in/3) using `Access`. Note that it might be used to modify a deeply nested structure on *any* level, unlike `Map.put`.

```elixir
update_in(
  ball_prop_list,
  [Access.filter(&match?(%{"id" => "cue"}, &1))],
  &Map.merge(&1, %{"velocity_x" => :new_velocity})
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll definitely check out the `Access` module.