# How do I update a list of maps with the values from another list of maps?

Tags: elixir

I have list of maps like so:

```
primary_list = [
  %{"id" => "cue", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => -15.0, "z" => 0.0},
  %{"id" => "ball_1", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 15.0, "z" => 0.0},
  %{"id" => "ball_2", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 17.0, "z" => 1.1},
  %{"id" => "ball_3", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 17.0, "z" => -1.1}
]
```

And another one, like so:

```
new_list = [
    %{"ball_1" => %{x: 14.684729230724962, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, 
    "cue" => %{x: 16.68472923072496, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}, 
    %{"ball_2" => %{x: 17.68472923072496, y: 0.0, z: 1.1}, 
    "cue" => %{x: 15.684729230724962, y: 0.0, z: 1.1}}, 
    %{"ball_3" => %{x: 17.68472923072496, y: 0.0, z: -1.1}, 
    "cue" => %{x: 15.684729230724962, y: 0.0, z: -1.1}}, 
    %{"ball_2" => %{x: 17.68472923072496, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, 
    "cue" => %{x: 15.684729230724962, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}, 
    %{"ball_3" => %{x: 17.68472923072496, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, 
    "cue" => %{x: 15.684729230724962, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}
]
```

How do I iterate over the second map, and apply the changes to the x, y, and z values to the first map based on the ID, while keeping the format of the first such that the final result would look something like this:

```
new_primary_list = [
    %{"id" => "cue", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 15.684729230724962, "z" => 0.0},
    %{"id" => "ball_1", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 14.684729230724962, "z" => 0.0},
    %{"id" => "ball_2", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 17.68472923072496, "z" => 0.0},
    %{"id" => "ball_3", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => 17.68472923072496, "z" => 0.0}
]
```

Some items are repeated, but the final value should be the last update (such as in the case of `ball_2` and `ball_3`). I tried this:

```
new_result = Enum.map(result, fn  res ->
    Enum.map(collision_map, fn cmap -> 
        Enum.map(cmap, fn {k, v} ->
            if res["id"] == k do
                res
                |> Map.put("x", v["x"])
                |> Map.put("z", v["z"])
            end
        end)
    end)
end)
```

But all I ended up with was a mess of list of a list of a list with lots of `nil` values:

```
[
    [nil, nil],  [nil, nil], 
    [%{"id" => "ball_3", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => nil, "z" => nil}, nil], 
    [nil, nil], 
    [%{"id" => "ball_3", "is_idle" => true, "velocity_x" => 0.0, "velocity_z" => 0.0, "x" => nil, "z" => nil}, nil]
]
```

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatten the `new_list` to make it easily iterable, and then walk through, updating the `primary_list`.

Note, that this is extremely inefficient and you’d better reconsider using `Map`s (e. g. with `id` as a key.)

```elixir
new_list
|> Enum.flat_map(& &1)
|> Enum.reduce(primary_list, fn {id, values}, acc ->
  update_in(
    acc,
    [Access.filter(& &1["id"] == id)],
    &Map.merge(&1, values)
  )
end)
```

---

You probably would need to convert keys of `new_list` to strings or like to make it work.

---

Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: I printed out the results of your code, but it seems to be similar to the format of `new_list`. Apologies if it wasn't clear, but I was hoping for a format more similar to `primary_list` (with the `{"id" => "cue, "velocity_x" => 0.0"...}` and such). However, I understand that my code right now is extremely inefficient. Could this be done easier if the `primary_list` was a map instead of a list of maps?

Comment: The result looks exactly as you wanted for `new_primary_list`, save for I didn’t bother to convert atom keys to string keys in the `new_list` as I mentioned in the bottom line of my answer. Just understand the solution and convert them yourself.

Comment: I do apologize again, but I copied your code and printed that out, and the results looks like this: https://imgur.com/VteV3LP / https://imgur.com/rbEqCnY. I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing something else wrong, as I'm very new to this. I was hoping it would look more like this: https://imgur.com/sVO3QPA

Comment: I am not sure how did you get these results. If you are testing them in `iex`, make sure you surround the code in the answer in parentheses.

Comment: Got it working! Your code was working straight up in IEX, but in the SDE I was working on, it didn't, until I added `new_list = (your code here)`. Thank you for your time and patience. Took a while, but I also changed the list of maps to just a map, and updated the rest of the code to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

I updated a little bit  Aleksei Matiushkin's answer:

```elixir
primary_list = Map.new(primary_list, & {&1["id"], &1}) # convert primary_list into a map

new_list 
|> Enum.flat_map(& &1) 
|> Enum.reduce(primary_list, fn {k, v}, acc -> # iterate over new_list and pass primary_list as accumulator
   Map.update!(
     acc, 
     k, 
     & Map.merge(&1, %{"x" => v.x, "y" => v.y, "z" => v.z}) # update primary_list  values with new_list
  )

 end)
|> Map.values() # covert result back into a list
```

Comment: `Enum.group_by(primary_list, & &1["id"])` reads better, but it requires `fn {k, [v]}, acc ->` in `reduce/3`. Dunno :)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned on your [previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750240/elixir-update-a-specific-value-in-a-list-of-maps#comment117995456_66750240), lists are not great for random access. Because you want to update specific elements by ID, it would be much better to store your state in a map, because that's what maps are designed for.

If you sanitize your data to make it easier to work with, the implementation can be quite simple:

```elixir
def update_state do
  {primary_map, new_list} = sanitize()

  Enum.reduce(new_list, primary_map, fn %{ball: ball, cue: cue}, primary_map ->
    primary_map = put_in(primary_map["cue"]["x"], cue.x)
    primary_map = put_in(primary_map["cue"]["y"], cue.y)
    primary_map = put_in(primary_map["cue"]["z"], cue.z)
    primary_map = put_in(primary_map[ball.id]["x"], ball.pos.x)
    primary_map = put_in(primary_map[ball.id]["y"], ball.pos.y)
    put_in(primary_map[ball.id]["z"], ball.pos.z)
  end)
  |> Map.values()
end
```

Output:

```elixir
[
  %{
    "id" => "ball_1",
    "is_idle" => true,
    "velocity_x" => 0.0,
    "velocity_z" => 0.0,
    "x" => 14.684729230724962,
    "y" => 0.0,
    "z" => 0.0
  },
  %{
    "id" => "ball_2",
    "is_idle" => true,
    "velocity_x" => 0.0,
    "velocity_z" => 0.0,
    "x" => 17.68472923072496,
    "y" => 0.0,
    "z" => 1.1
  },
  %{
    "id" => "ball_3",
    "is_idle" => true,
    "velocity_x" => 0.0,
    "velocity_z" => 0.0,
    "x" => 17.68472923072496,
    "y" => 0.0,
    "z" => -1.1
  },
  %{
    "id" => "cue",
    "is_idle" => true,
    "velocity_x" => 0.0,
    "velocity_z" => 0.0,
    "x" => 15.684729230724962,
    "y" => 0.0,
    "z" => 0.0
  }
]
```

---

In `sanitize` I did two things:

1. Convert the state to a map.

```elixir
Map.new(primary_list, fn item -> {item["id"], item} end)
```

This gives us:

```elixir
%{
  "ball_1" => %{
    "id" => "ball_1",
    "is_idle" => true,
    "velocity_x" => 0.0,
    "velocity_z" => 0.0,
    "x" => 15.0,
    "z" => 0.0
  }, ...
}
```

Which is much easier to work with, allowing us to use `put_in` with the ball id above.

2. Convert `new_list` to have consistent keys. Your ball keys are `ball_1`, `ball_2`, etc, but that makes it hard to access them programmatically from a loop. It's much nicer to have a consistent id: `ball`.

```elixir
for item <- new_list do
  [id] = Map.keys(item) -- ["cue"]

  %{
    ball: %{id: id, pos: item[id]},
    cue: item["cue"]
  }
end
```

This gives us `new_list` in this format, allowing us to look up `ball` for each item:

```elixir
[
   %{
     ball: %{id: "ball_1", pos: %{x: 14.684729230724962, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}},
     cue: %{x: 16.68472923072496, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}
   }, ...
]
```

Here is the full `sanitize` function:

```elixir
def sanitize do
  primary_list = primary_list()
  primary_map = Map.new(primary_list, fn item -> {item["id"], item} end)

  new_list = new_list()

  new_list =
    for item <- new_list do
      [id] = Map.keys(item) -- ["cue"]

      %{
        ball: %{id: id, pos: item[id]},
        cue: item["cue"]
      }
    end

  {primary_map, new_list}
end
```